# best data structure for table

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary, typescript, data-structures

I'm trying to find the best data structure for visualize this UI:
[image]

I'm using javascript/typescript with Angular and I should be able to add/remove/update items. Please consider also that I will have lot of rows and columns and up to 100 non-repeated items in each cell.
So far I'm considering this data structure:

```
var data = new Map<string, Map<string, Set<Item>>>();
```

where the strings are rowKeyN and columnKeyN and Set contains the items in each cell.

This kind of datastructure seems a bit complicated to use but is the best that I found in terms of performance.
What do you think? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Answer from [What are the data structures behind a spreadsheet?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/219301/91866)

Comment: are the number of rows and columns fixed?

Comment: Yes they are fixed

Comment: @Lelezeus It's probably easier to use an Array of Arrays with **index mapping** to the header names. Basically each *row* is an array. They you'd have a seperate **map** to map the array index to its corresponding header. does that make sense ?

Comment: maybe I get your idea, a step forward could be something like: Map<string, Items[]> where : 
<"row1&col1", [Item1]>
<"row1&col2", [Item2, Item3]>
<"row2&col1", [Item2]>
etc.

Answer (score -1):

Bumped into this question - you should look at Guava's (for Java) Table representation - where the last case you would get a List

[see more details here for Guava's table](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table)

but in short:
taken from the docs:

```
Table<Vertex, Vertex, Double> weightedGraph = HashBasedTable.create();
weightedGraph.put(v1, v2, 4);
weightedGraph.put(v1, v3, 20);
weightedGraph.put(v2, v3, 5);

weightedGraph.row(v1); // returns a Map mapping v2 to 4, v3 to 20
weightedGraph.column(v3); // returns a Map mapping v1 to 20, v2 to 5
```

In your case it would be `Table<Vertex,Vertex,Array>`

I came here while trying to search something like the above for Typescript - I haven't found it - yet - if anyone knows of such an implementation - let me know